# vias in Meandering Monopole Antenna

Tags: rf, antenna, pcb-antenna

I've recently been using the Texas Instruments CC1310 LaunchPad for some prototyping and now want to make a custom board. I would like the RF performance of my custom board to be as similar to that of the Evaluation Kit as possible, so I am trying to implement the same Meandering Monopole Antenna

http://www.ti.com/lit/an/swra227e/swra227e.pdf

One think is confusing me and that is the use of vias in the antenna. the antenna is on both layers of my 2-layer PCB, and it looks like the layers are connected with vias. In the images within the PDF referenced above, it just looks like closely placed small vias aling the centre of the antenna.

On the LaunchPad evaluation module, they are staggered and along the edge of the antenna, which you can just about see here:

http://dev.ti.com/tirex/content/ti-rtos_cc13xx_cc26xx/ti-rtos_cc13xx_cc26xx__2.16.00.08/resources/cc1310LaunchPad/project0/images/cc1310_launchpad_explained.PNG

I don't know much about antenna theory, but have successfully implemented PCB antennas from reference designs in the past.

Are the vias necessary to connect both layers of the antenna?

Does poor placement of the vias negatively affect RF performance?

Why are the vias placed differently in the two designs I referenced above?

Are there any rules to follow when placing vias in antennas?

Comment: If you don't copy their exact design, including PCB material and stack up, you'll might end up with a different impedance. Unless you have the proper tools to dimension a new matching circuit, you don't want that.

Comment: The first reference in the PDF above has some data but no indication of why the design is as given.  I would guess the vias connect an identical serpentine on the opposite surface (and perhaps even on internal layers if multilayer PCB),  This will increase the radiating element characteristics (from ribbon to box) and probably widen the bandwidth, not sure, there is a lot of magic involved by most accounts.

Comment: The design note specifies that having the antenna on both sides increases the bandwidth, suggesting it would work as a 1 sided antenna. Does this mean that even if I have a slightly different placement of vias it is still likely to be better than a single sided antenna?